# Concerning Dual Processor Motherboards

Tags: cpu, motherboard, cpu-speed

I've read about dual processor mother boards, but some things don't seem to make themselves clear. I have a few questions:

1. Is a computer with two 1GHz single-core CPUs just as fast as a computer with a single 1GHz dual-core CPU?
2. Can you just jam in any old processor that'll fit, or does the processor have to support it?
3. Do they have to be the same model/speed?
4. In the end does anything really matter?

EDIT. New questions:

5. If I only put one CPU in, can it be of any type? Or does it still have to be able to support the dual processing?
6. How might one go about finding CPUs that support the aforementioned dual processing?

That is all, thank you

Comment: As far as I know, Intel only had the Xeon processors and maybe a few of the Pentium processors (before they got multi-threading and/or multi-core) capable of multi-processors on a motherboard. There were a number of RISC processors that supported multi-processors also. Sun had a unit that supported 64 processors, but I forget if they were RISC or Xeon.

Comment: Early celerons also worked. (Those were basically PPro design. I ran two motherboard with dual celerons :))  And AMD did fine with their Athlon MP series.

Answer (score 0):

> Is a computer with two 1GHz single-core CPUs just as fast as a computer with
>   a single 1GHz dual-core CPU?

Assuming we are comparing the same generation CPU's: Yes, about as fast.

That is not to say that is is always precisely the same speed:

- E.g. There might be differences if a task migrates between CPU0 and CPU1. On a dual core CPU that might mean that said tasks keeps the shared L2 or shared L3 cache. In which case it will be faster on the dual core.
- Or the other ay around: Dual socket motherboards often have two CPU's and two sets of memory controllers. Memory bandwidth can be up to twice as high. If you access large amounts of memory (large enough that no significant part fits into the cache) then the dual socket system might be faster.

> Can you just jam in any old processor that'll fit, or does the processor
>   have to support it?

The processor needs to support it. And in the case of most motherboards you will need two identical model CPU's running at the same speed.

> Do they have to be the same model/speed?

See above.

> In the end does anything really matter?

Who will be there to know that any of this had meaning for us?